# How to not animate caption with SlidesJS

Tags: jquery

I'm using SlidesJS (http://www.slidesjs.com), and I've got it working the way i want it to except for 2 things.  One, I need the captions to not do the same animation as the images.  Specifically, I need them to not animate at all, just change instantly. [Here's a jsfiddle that should suffice](http://jsfiddle.net/bzrDK/42/)

I've included the entire slidesjs bit in the javascript part of the jsfiddle so u can edit it easily.  The part that you call is just:

```
$(function(){
  $('.slides').slides({
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: '<?=STATIC_ROOT?>images/loading.gif',
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
    hoverPause: false,
    effect: 'dpg',
  });
```

});

dpg is just a custom effect that i made so i wouldn't erase the normal effects of slide and fade.

The other part that isn't working is that the animation doesn't work the very first time. After the first transition, it works like it should. I can probably figure out how to fix this part though, so mainly I need help with the first part, but extra credit if you can help me with both. Thanks in advance.